# Does Vertica supports Virtual Columns?

Tags: database, currency, create-table, vertica

Does **Vertica** supports **Virtual Columns ?**
*I read the docs and I cannot find it!*

Use :
I have a table :

```
create table test(
id number,
name varchar(12),
account data_type as function_name
);
```

- since Vertica does not support the currency format from other countries outside US, I am looking for a work-around this when I populate my tables that hold currency columns.
- I will create a special format function in C++ and then applied to the column definition.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the manual doesn't mentioned virtual columns it's highly likely they are not supported. What are you actually trying to achieve? Formatting prices should be done in the frontend, just store the value and the currency in your table.

Comment: Currency format in Brasil is "," comma for grouping and "." point for decimal. And in US is the other way around. So any currency that comes from other RDBMS has to either be transformed at load time, apply currency locale(which vertica does not support)on the column or create an external user defined function that will be used at load time or inside the database when data si altered or inserted!!!

Comment: A numeric column does **not** have a format. The format is only "defined" when you actually display the values. So if you simply use `numeric` (or whatever the equivalent in Vertica is) you shouldn't have a problem - just do the formatting in your application then. You don't need any special data type for that. And besides: the SQL standard only defines how a numeric literal should be "formatted": Using `.` for the decimals and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to my problem:

```
dbadmin=> SELECT translate(to_char(123456.77,'R$ 999G999G999D99'), ',.', '.,');
     translate
--------------------
 R$      123.456,77
(1 row)
```

By using the translate function i can replace string pieces in the output.
THX